# Grid For HTML app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I'm trying to make an app for android using PhoneGap,HTML5. I need to use an UI that should have one grid two text boxes and one button

My scenario is textbox1 is an [***autocomplete***](http://github.com/commadelimited/autoComplete.js/blob/master/readme.md) which is filled with some product names user can select a product then in the next textbox ie textbox2 user should give the quantity(selected products quantity) after this user should click on the button (called ADD) then these items need to appends to the grid the grid should have 4 columns (*`1.Sl.No,2.Product Name,3.Quanity,4.Delete/Edit`*)

I've searched a lot most of the available examples are directly filling data from the server.I couldn't find one suits my needs.

Helps/Suggestions are much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Is the datasource `textbox1` remote or embedded in your script? Either way, [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) would be a perfect match to your need.

For your data table (a.k.a "grid"), it doesn't seem to have much feature so you can simply use a `<table>` tag in HTML and use jQuery to play with the data inside it. If you need more fancy features a 3rd-party datatable library (e.g. https://www.datatables.net/) would be good.

Comment: Am using this https://github.com/commadelimited/autoComplete.js/blob/master/readme.md

Comment: Which one should I prefer is there any sample code or something ??

Comment: From the document, both `autoComplete.js` and jQuery-UI supports remote and local data source so either would be okay.

Comment: Ok. Let me try that :).