# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'orientation' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the follow up of question [Grid For HTML app's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31933838/grid-for-html-app/31933917) based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31933917/4874879)

I've tried to create the data table using https://www.datatables.net/ the js files coming with this added to my existing project folder

and following is my `<head>` tag

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
<title>AndRemedy</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jqm.autoComplete-1.5.2-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/login.js"></script>
<!-- DataTable reference starts here -->
<!-- DataTables CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="media/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  
<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="media/js/jquery.js"></script>
  
<!-- DataTables -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

</head>
```

But when I run this getting

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'orientation' of undefined : jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.js:45

Note : Am trying to develop a hybrid app using PhoneGap,HTML5

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, there's a TypeError in you jquery.mobil script. You can try to update it with [the last version](http://jquerymobile.com/download/). Don't forget the stylesheet.

If you still have an error, try the uncompressed version.

Comment: It can't throw errors if you're not using it. That make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You are using referencing two jquery files in your script. Only one is needed. Remove the first one and move the rest of the jquery and it's dependency files to the body tag.

Comment: you meant this `<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: <!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="media/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

Comment: But If I remove `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="media/js/jquery.js">` the datatable wont work

Comment: so what's the purpose of <script src="js/jquery.js"></script> located just below the <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />